# How to add command to Screen Command Bar in Light Switch?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

How do I add command to Screen Command Bar, that is accessible across all screens in LightSwitch application(like Save and Refresh)?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent discussion of 2 options here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/7848af2b-d57d-4189-86ef-1e68cd3754f3

If you've only got a few screens then the cut & paste option is less complex than using the IShellCommandGroupProvider component.